# Проблема в запуске виджета PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Создаю небольшую игру с графическим интерфейсом на pyqt5. При запуске программы в .py выдает ошибку qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Пытался переустановить PyQt5 - не помогло. Код предоставлен ниже.

```
import sys
from widget import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()


#Game logic


#Exit
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Попробуйте сначала переустановить **Python**(новую версию), а потом **PyQT**. Если работаете в Pycharm, проверьте, какая версия там поставлена.